# Can laravel lighthouse package connect with Fauna database?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, graphql, faunadb

As Lighthouse uses GraphQL and Fauna database also uses GraphQL so it is possible to use Fauna database with laravel using Lighthouse package.

Fauna database does not have a direct package to operate with laravel. But there are tutorials where Fauna database can work with PHP with GraphQL.

[How to use Fauna with graphql and php](https://fauna.com/blog/how-to-use-fauna-with-graphql-and-php)